# Как накатить уникальный индекс на таблицу с дублирующимися записями

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ name    ║ order_id  ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ "One"   ║ 1         ║ 
║ "One"   ║ 1         ║ 
║ "One"   ║ 1         ║
║ "One"   ║ 2         ║
║ "Two"   ║ 3         ║
║ "Two"   ║ 3         ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Нужно покрыть ее уникальным индексом, но проблема в том. что в таблице есть дублирующиеся данные и индекс не накатывается.

Сейчас пытаюсь написать запрос, который убирает дубликаты записей, пытаюсь использовать `row_number()`:

```
delete from `table` 
  where (select 
         row_number() over (partition by name, order_id) as rn 
         from `table`) != 1;
```

Получаю:

> Подзапрос в выражении вернул больше одной строки.

Как удалить дупликаты в таблице, в которой нет id?(Все способы из гугла опираются на id)
Или может есть способ накатить индекс на таблицу "насильно"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеется в виду уникальность по обеим колонкам, то что-то типа:

```sql
DELETE FROM "table" AS "a" USING "table" AS "b"
 WHERE "a"."ctid" > "b"."ctid"
   AND "a"."name" = "b"."name"
   AND "a"."order_id" = "b"."order_id"
```

Comment: Работает! Насколько безопасно это использовать? Можно быть уверенным, что такой запрос в любом случае оставит одну запись?

Comment: @Oleg ЕМНИП, `ctid` уникален на время транзакции, так что должно оставить только по одной записи. На всех моих данных всегда работало.

Answer (score 2):

В postgresql есть системная колонка `ctid` которая содержит физический адрес записи в таблице, можно использовать ее для адресации удаляемых записей:

```
delete from "table"
   where ctid in(
     select ctid from (
       select ctid, row_number() over(partition by name, order_id) rn
         from "table"
      ) A where rn>1
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас не восьмая версия, то:

```
WITH 
delete_cte AS (DELETE FROM test RETURNING *),
select_cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM delete_cte)
INSERT INTO test SELECT * FROM select_cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=62e2db0548856cf6274b48effb770eb9)

Можно и в обратном порядке.

```
WITH 
select_cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test),
delete_cte AS (DELETE FROM test)
INSERT INTO test SELECT * FROM select_cte
```